# How can I configure doorkeeper so that more than one client can authenticate with the same username and password?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, oauth-2.0, doorkeeper

I'm using the doorkeeper gem with the [resource owner password credentials flow](https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper/wiki/Using-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-flow), if separate clients authenticate with the same username and password they end up using the same access token. This means that a client will no longer have a valid access token if another client has refreshed the access token.

How can I configure doorkeeper so that more than one client can authenticate with the same username and password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of doorkeeper, v0.7.2, fixes this issue. Now, an access token is always issued on request, see https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper/commit/23bc9a0a0a93be35e40dd44d87417b16339efde5 for the details.